How to write a Checkbox with terms in laravel
I have the Sponzy script written in Laravel and for ccbill to allow me to accept credit card i have to add a checkbox for the creator to accept the performers consent.  I know who to get the checkbox to work in using java but not using Laravel.  When i tried using the java code in the sponzy script when you check the box it automatically sends the information without clicking the button.  How do i write the checkbox code using Laravel?
<form action="/action_page.php">
  Checkbox: <input type="checkbox" id="sendData" name="test" required> <label for="checkbox"> I agree to these <a href="/PerformerAgreement.pdf" target="_blank">Performer Agreement</a>.</ label>



  <button class="btn btn-1 btn-success btn-block mt-5" id="sendData" type="submit">{{trans('general.send_approval')}}</button>

</form>



<script>
function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("sendData").required;
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = x;
}
</script>

i tried writing the script in java and expected it to work, but it didn't.
